# How do i include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h> for NDK toolchain's gcc

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, android-ndk

first of all, i got into a problem last time when trying to compile a c program to linux- arm architecture, for using it in an android app later. I succeeded in doing so, and i'll write later a post on how to use the NDK standalone toolchain.

Now that i've finally got that working, I'm trying to compile a .c file, which has a line  "include bluetooth/bluetooth.h" in it. When I try to compile the file, i get a: "no such file or directory" error on it. My makefile includes the word "-libbluetooth".
The standart NDK gcc library does'nt have a bluetooth support, so i've downloaded "libbluetooth.so" from my device, which is what i needed to make it work, according to the brief research on the subject over the internet. I still get the same error.

I'll be glad to know if anyone has encountered the same problem.
thank u
Dekel

Comment: how did you solve this problem. i am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the bluetooth library to link your program; but to compile it, you need the appropriate headers. **libbluetooth.so** is not part of Android official API, but luckily you can find it sources and the include files that declare its public *(but unofficial)* API, if you download the AOSP source tree, according to Google's [instructions](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). Actually, you are interested in a small part of the tree: `./external/bluetooth/bluez/lib`. There you will find the `bluetooth/bluetooth.h` include file. In your `Android.mk`, you will have a line similar to:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(AOSP_ROOT)/external/bluetooth/bluez/lib
```