# Android NDK arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am trying to compile android-NDK project which uses L2CAP Bluetooth profile.When I compile in eclipse with android-ndk-r8d-windows and android-sdk-4.2  I am getting following error

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: libbluetooth.so: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libl2cap_BTComm.so] Error 1
```

Please help me in solving this

Comment: just try this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552868/how-do-i-include-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-ndk-toolchains-gcc

Comment: @Lochana Ragupathy i am new to NDK concept,I am unable to understand the procedure,please can you explain AOSP source tree AOSP_ROOT concept?

Comment: AOSP_ROOT its is a environmental variable which has a path where the source code is present

Comment: wat was told in the above link was you have to include the header files which are required to compile the library

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy I have included header files.It was working fine before, but now after i changed my OS from xp to windows 7 and reinstalled cygwin I am getting this error.

Comment: oh i am not able to exactly tell wat will be your problem since i used linux for NDK compilation rather than cygwin. Continue your search and please share your results

Comment: In addition to the include, you'll either need an import library or to add the flag which tells the linker to ignore undefined library symbols (and hope that they will exist at runtime on the device)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in Ubuntu 12.04 while building the ndk project using ndk-build.
The problem is the missing g++ compiler.  After install a GNU C++ compiler it works now.

Interestingly, when I recompile the whole project from fresh it got the same complain again.
(before I was using cygwin and ubuntu to compile the same project and it was working)

Comment: This answer seems a bit unlikely: it's an error message being generated *by* the ndk's C++ compiler, so obviously *that* is not missing.  And it references a library for the android target, so it's not clear why a *host* C++ compiler would be needed for that particular step, though almost everyone doing such work would have the build-essential meta package installed as a matter of course.

Answer (score 0):

Its been over a year now since the last reply but I think the answer is to use the -l option of g++ to add the directory with the lib to g++'s search paths.